# Why is $\gamma(t) = 1 + 3e^{2\pi i t}$ null-homotopic in $\mathbb C \setminus \{ -1 \}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I want to show that $\gamma(t) = 1 + 3e^{2\pi i t}$ is null-homotopic in $\mathbb C \setminus \{ -1 \}$.

[image]

I usually show this by finding a simply connected space that contains the loop and that, in this case, is a substet of $\mathbb C \setminus \{ -1 \}$, (for example, a half-plane), because $\mathbb U$ simply connected $\Rightarrow$ every loop is null-homotopic in $\mathbb U$. However, I am having trouble with this one because I am not seeing a simply connected space that contains the loop and that is contained in $\mathbb C \setminus \{ -1 \}$.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot prove it, since it is not true. Note that$$\oint_\gamma\frac1{z+1}\,\mathrm dz=2\pi i\operatorname{Ind}_\gamma(-1)=2\pi i.$$If $\gamma$ was null-homotopic in $\Bbb C\setminus\{-1\}$, the previous integral would be equal to $0$.